# Purpose of Loop Element in tWriteJSONField in TOS

Tags: json, talend

I am not that familiar with the JSON/XML components in TOS.

I am not clear what the loop element does.  I read somewhere that whatever you set as the loop element, you get one json document produced for each item.  I may be getting confused with "group by" as in the example below I was expecting 1 JSON document for the 2 records sharing MANAGER_ID = 200.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We use loop element in order to get the output in the form of  Json array

You can go through the following links for better understanding

**Example job:**

[image: Example job]

---

**Output:**

[image: Output]

Comment: Hi, thanks  - I am assuming somewhere in there you have a Group By clause in the tWriteJSON component, as I can't get my "loop element" to work in this way unless I also add a group at a higher level.   I understand (sort of) what it is doing, but I am sure I read that the loop element is what drives the creation of individual JSON documents.